# Is the order relation in this problem well-defined?

Tags: order-theory

A friend and I are working through Munkres' topology text, and are having trouble on the problem shown. It seems to me that without defining a method to obtain *n* the order relation makes no sense. Am I missing something?

[image: problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's just a missing quantifier:

> $\bf x < \bf y$ if there exists $n \in \omega$ such that $x_n < y_n$ and $x_i = y_i$ for $i > n$.

Comment: That would make sense. I became very hung up on the truthiness of *x < y* hinging upon my choice of *n*, and couldn't see the forest for the trees. Thank you!